# Robot Framework Jenkins WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: jenkins, webdriver

I have the Robot framework setup to run with Chrome WebDriver on my local machine and this runs as expected.

When I run exactly the same command through Jenkins on the same machine, I receive the following error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

If I echo PATH I can see that I do have the Chrome Webdriver in the `usr/local/bin` directory.

I believe my issue to be that the JENKINS_USER is set to system so therefore cannot access the ChromeDriver that I currently have stored in 'usr/local/bin'

how can I make the chromeDriver accessible to the user that Jenkins run under?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is an option inside of Jenkins that enables you to set the path of whereever you have stroed the webdriver

go to Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Global Properties: Environment Variables